# Get an environment variable from kubernetes pods and store it in an array

Tags: kubernetes, jsonpath

The use case is to get the environment variable *COUNTRY from all the pods running in a namespace

```
kubectl get pods podname -n namespace -o 'jsonpath={.spec.containers[0].env[?(@.name~="^COUNTRY")].value}'
```

This does not seem to work. any lead?

Comment: Using the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-client-libraries) with your choice of programming language will probably be easier than scripting `kubectl`, especially trying to fit non-trivial logic into a jsonpath expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve this information using the following command:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.containers[*].env[*].name}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[*].env[*].value}{"\n"}{end}' | grep COUNTRY | cut -f 2
```

It will return the variables content as follows:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.containers[*].env[*].name}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[*].env[*].value}{"\n"}{end}' | grep VAR | cut -f 2

123456
7890123
```

Comment: but it will search for only COUNTRY env variable what if the country env variable startes with NEW_COUNTRY or OLD_COUNTRY?

Comment: This does not woek

Comment: Please, try with this command: `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.spec.containers[*].env[*].name}{"\t"}{.spec.containers[*].env[].value}{"\n"}{end}' | grep COUNTRY | cut -f 2`

Comment: Is there a way I can fetch the chartname for a pod in kubernetes, I can see label but cant fetch `kubectl get pods  pr3819-mysql-797cbd755d-r2sxj -n pr3819 --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.labels.chart"`

Comment: Something like this? `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.metadata.labels.chart}{"\n"}{end}'` This will return Pod name and Chart Name in the same line. You can get only Chart Name with `{.items[*].metadata.labels.chart}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].env[?(@.name=="COUNTRY")].value}'
```

Hope this helps. I was just able to run it on mine and it worked the best.